# Purpose of Overloading 'new' and 'delete' in 'SharedRefBase' in Android's `binder_interface_utils.h`, and Issue with `std::make_shared`

Tags: android, c++

In the Android codebase, specifically in the `binder_interface_utils.h` file, I've noticed that the `new` and `delete` operators are overloaded within the `SharedRefBase` class. Could someone provide some insights into why this is the case?

Furthermore, when creating a `std::shared_ptr` of `SharedRefBase`, it seems one must use the internal `make` function provided by `SharedRefBase` itself instead of `std::make_shared`. When I tried using `std::make_shared`, it led to a crash during deallocation on Android 12. Could you provide some explanation why `std::make_shared` would induce this problem?

Here's the relevant code snippet for reference:

```cpp
    class SharedRefBase {
       ...
        static void operator new(size_t s) { return std::malloc(s); }
        static void operator delete(void p) { std::free(p); }
       ...
        template 
        static std::shared_ptr make(Args&&... args) {
            ...
        }
       ...
    }
```

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`SharedRefBase` has a pseudo `shared_from_this` implementation.

That requires control over how `shared_ptr`s are created, as during construction of the `shared_ptr` the logical equivalent of a `weak_ptr` must be stored.

In `std` this ends up modifying `make_shared` as well as the `shared_ptr` cobstruft-from-pointer code to inject that `weak_ptr` equivalent into `shared_from_this` derived classes.

As `SharedRefBase` is not part of the `std` library, and the `std` library does not expose customization hooks to inject the `weak_ptr` equivalent state during `shared_ptr` construction, you must use its `shared_ptr` construction methods (static `make`, or the `ref` method) to cobstruct the `shared_ptr`.

Why it doesn't use `shared_from_this` is something I do not know.

I would suspect based on the new/delete operator overloading that it actually stores the information for the `shared_ptr` state next to the object, thus blocking memory fragmentation of shared ptr managed objects that use that base class.  But that is just something I suspect.